# select css image locator same class in robotframework

Tags: css, robotframework

I have faced a problem with select css locator in robotframework.
PageA has 1 Pic I can use **click image css=div.z-toolbarbutton-cnt > img**
but PageB has 20 pic in the same class. I want to choose once.
Please suggest me for this issues.

**click image     css=div.z-toolbarbutton-cnt img[src="filename"]**
It's not work.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a CssSelector if you know a id of image, like this :
`div.z-toolbarbutton-cnt > img:nth-child(1)` (the 1 for the fisrt picture) or you can use this  for contains : 
`div.z-toolbarbutton-cnt > img[src*="menu_payment"]`